# How to increase the current in this circuit?

Tags: led, bjt, infrared, current-limiting

Im trying to build a circuit to send information using IR led, using pulse signals (Im trying to mimic a home appliance remote control).

My leds ([datasheet](http://www.vishay.com/docs/81011/tsal6400.pdf)) operate at 1.3V, and their maximum pulse current is rated 200mA

I need a very strong signal and since the "commands" I send are quite short, I understand that there's not much harm in operating it at higher currents.

I tried to use two IR leds in series, aiming to 300~mA current flow trough the leds.

I did the following calculation:

```
Vs = 5V
I = 300mA
Vdrop of each led = 1.3V
so R = 5v - 2.6v / 0.300A.
```

I managed to build `22Ohm || 10Ohm = 7~ Ohm`
Im controlling the base of my BJT 2N2222A transistor using my controller gpio, which is rated at 3.3V.
In reality, I measured 80mA, which isn't what I expected.
I expected it to be in saturation, since:

```
Vb = 3.3V
Vc = 0V
Ve = 0
Ve < Vb > Vc => Sat.
```

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftajL1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where are the LED data sheet links, please?

Comment: You have no base resistor in Q1. It's like shorting out the 3.3 V supply with a diode.

Comment: @transistor, http://www.vishay.com/docs/81011/tsal6400.pdf. Its a bit misleading but the Base input is PWM from GPIO 3.3V. Can you explain why the resistor is needed and what is the effect at the moment? If I add a 1kOhm resistor the current will drop by half. How do I calculate the required resistance?

Comment: Try to use a constant current source rather than using a transistor controlled at base.A simple current source can be built by using LM317.If you think that purchasing LM317 is costly,try to use two BJT's in current mirror configuration.This will be more stable than controlling a BJT with microcontoller and also doesn't require much calculations.I tried it.surely it'll work fine

Comment: Ok, you're wanting to exceed the max _PULSE_ current for your LEDs? That doesn't sound like a great idea...exceeding max continuous in a pulse is fine, but max pulse is intended tl be fairly concrete. Also, if you check tje Vforward characteristics, thkse LEDs have a slow-response to forward biasing, with Vforward kf up to 3V per LED at only 10KHz!

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB, I've been mislead to understand that for pulsed signals its will still work OK. I would stick with 200mA max current.

Comment: Also, why are you using PWM for the signal when it should be a simple pulsed signal for the remote? Were you trying to use PWM to control voltage/power consumption of the LEDs?

Comment: "using my controller gpio, which is rated at 3.3V" - which controller?

Comment: Also, if you're using an of-the-shelf 'multimeter' to test the current of a signal that's pulsed @ 38khz _and_ OOK modulated at several hertz, the meter won't bd able to sample fast enough to tell you the _actual peak_ current. You are likely getting >=200mA peak current through your LEDs already.

Comment: You should instead use a nfet if you'd like to drive the transistor with a voltage. A NPN transistor is all about ic = beta*ib, hence you need a resistor at the base to correctly polarize the diode (vbe = 0.7).

Comment: Im using RPI. GPIO can output up to 16mA. I measure the current by taking a test led and using continous signal, measure quickly and turn it off. Thats the best I can do with my home equipment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to being reminded to use an N-MOSFET, I came up with this circuit for you:
[image: LED Driver]

The N-MOSFET should have a drain-source impedance of ~1.5ohm @ Vgs=3.3V (from your GPIO pin), so taking 5Vdrive - 2.7V for 2x 1.35V LED drops, that leaves 10ohm for the resistor to give: 2.3V/11.5ohm=200mA through your LEDs.

Comment: I updated with link to the led spreadsheet. I wasnt aware of Vce(sat) drop, thanks. so how do I reach 212mA? I tested and each led is indeed 1.3V drop. How do I calculate the base resistor correctly?

Comment: For the base resistor, you take Vsource - Vbe, then divide by your desired base current. The only problem is that on checking the datasheet, your 2N2222a can have a Vbe anywhere from 0.6-2.0V, so that makes things a  it more 'guess & check.'

Comment: Vce(sat) is much less than 0.7. You may be looking an Vbe(sat).

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast just noticed that...I tossed out that 0.7 based on 'average' npn vce sat of 0.7V, like they taught us decades ago in EE class (although come to think of it, I'm not sure I've ever actually used a transistor with that exact response). .... Should've pulled up a 2n2222a datasheet first.

Comment: Actually, the definition of saturation is VCE < VBE, so 0.7 is pretty much the top of the range for silicon small-signal saturation. 0.2 to 0.4 is much more common, and has been since my own student days (which are likely a good deal farther in the past than yours).

Comment: @e-r-a-n Answer updated to work with OP's specified LEDs & signal source

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB, It seems I do run into many problems using BJT since it requires specified currents out of my controller which I cant give. At maximum I managed to get 80mA. N-MOSFET arent dependant on currents? Seems like much simpler solution! It seems that I should just buy some of those and re-design my circuit.

Comment: N-MOSFET (and all other FETs) is voltage-controlled, with extremely high-impedance gate input.

Comment: & Thanks to @lucas92 for the reminder re: using an N-MOSFET in the first place.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB According to Wikipedia, N-MOSFET is in saturation mode when `Vds >Vgs - Vth`. But here, `Vd = 5v - 2v - 2.7v = 0.3v, Vs=0, Vg = 3.3v`. So `Vds=0.3v, Vgs = 3.3v`. Thats not fullfiling the saturation mode equation. What am I missing now?

Comment: @e-r-a-n - Yes, a MOSFET is much easier in this application. But if you do go that route, be aware that many MOSFETs are not guaranteed to turn on properly at 3.3 volts gate drive. The FET specified is called a "logic-drive" MOSFET, and you need to be sure to use something like it. If you are looking at a data sheet, the characteristic you 're looking for is called "gate turn-on voltage" or something like, and the shorthand is Vgs(th). Make sure the MAXIMUM value is 2 volts or less.

Comment: @e-r-a-n The specified N-MOSFET will conduct current from drain to source whenever Vgs is greater than Vgs(th) (threshold 'turn on' voltage) which for the specified transistor is 0.7V. Then, according to the spec sheet, the max average impedance at Vgs=2.5V (below your 3.3V drive) is 1.5ohm (and only 1.0ohm @ Vgs=4V). I ran my calculations based on the 0.3V channel resistance to your 200mA load under those conditions. "Saturation," as per that definition means that a MOSFET is conducting as much current as it possibly can @ the current gate voltage.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB - No, 0.7 is the MINIMUM Vgs(th). Maximum is about 1.6, and you have to plan for worst-case. Plus, that is for a drain current of 250 uA, so slightly more than 1.6 volts is necessary for 300 mA. Figure 2 volts as a safe guess.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Thank you; re-checking the datasheet I had that spec weong in my comment ... Vgs(th) min=0.8V & max=1.4V. Too bad we can't edit comments. I think the rest of that comment was good, though. The 1.5ohm d-s impedance is max for Vgs-4.0V & 'Typical' for Vgs-2.5V, so should be a fairly safe approximation of resistance at his stated 3.3V drive.

Comment: Thank you both. The typical specs show Rds with Id=10mA for Vgs=2.5V. that current value is the minimum? By looking at the next page, Id is effected by two values - either Vds > 0.25V (approx.), or Vgs > 2.5V (here I would have Vgs=3.3v, Vds=0.3V) Both these values will result in closed circuit with the ability to let more around 200mA of current flow? It actually doesn't even matter reaching saturation or not because I just care opening it enough for my use (Unlike the problem I had with the BJT transistor)

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB, If taking a transistor with Rds(on)=~0Ohm (instead of 1.5ohm you took), it means the entire resistance is the resistor I  use to limit the current (without the 1.5Ohm you already have in the transistor you used). So it means Vds=0. Does it make any difference regarding the current able to flow trough? Im using RFP30N06LE, and its unclear what the current ratings are

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is base drive. Your controller GPIO is unable to provide adequate current, even though your are effectively shorting it to ground (I say "effectively" because 0.7 volts, the actual limit, is much less than 3.3).

If you look at [a 2N2222 data sheet](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/dl/Scans-005/Scans-00104443.pdf) and look at the saturation curve at the bottom of page 494, you'll see that, for 200 to 300 mA, you can hope for a saturation voltage in the range of 0.2 volts ASSUMING A GAIN OF 10. In your circuit, with a 5 volt supply, 2 1.3 LED drops and 0.2 volts across the transistor, you can expect a current of $$i=\frac{V}{R} = \frac{5-2.6-0.2}{8} =  275\text{ mA}$$ This in turn requires a base drive of 27 mA, and your GPIO will never produce it.

So, how to proceed? Well, you need to boost the current capacity of your GPIO pins, and you can do this with the following circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7Jhv8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Two extra transistors, rather than 1, are required to maintain the operating sense, in other words to turn the LEDs on with a logic high on the GPIO pin.

Of course, if you need an extra PNP anyways, there is no need for 3 transistors. You can do it with

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3TSyr.png)</sup>

This circuit will probably work well, but it's very slightly iffy in terms of total gain, and may not give quite as much current as you expected, but it will be much better than your first attempt.

The PNP can be any good signal transistor. I've shown both 2N2907 and 2N3906. Both will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things wrong here:

You say the LEDs are rated for 200 mA pulsed operation.  That already takes into account that they will be on for a short time.  You don't get to pulse them at 300 mA and still expect them to work as otherwise specified.

No, you don't have 3.3 V B-E on the transistor, at least not unless you've already blow it out.  You need to control the current thru the base, not the voltage across it.  If the 3.3 V signal can source about 10 mA or so, then connect it with a resistor in series.  Figure 700 mV B-E drop, so you want about (2.6 V)/(10 mA) = 260 Ω.

To test the LEDs, you can run them separately without the transistor.  They will drop 2.6 V total, so (2.6 V)/(200 mA) = 13 Ω with 5 V applied should be about right.

However, at this current, the voltage drop of the LEDs is likely higher than the 1.3 V specified for steady current.  It would be useful to use a bit higher voltage so that you can use a higher current setting resistor.  That will make your circuit more immune to LED voltage variations.

You might try driving each LED separately with its own transistor.  That will be less efficient overall, but will allow for better control of the LED currents.  Then you can drive the base directly with the 3.3 V logic signal, put the resistor in series with the emitter, and the LED in series with the collector.  The transistor will then act like a controlled current sink.  Figure 700 mV B-E, so that leaves 2.6 V on the base.  The emitter resistor is then (2.6 V)/(200 mA) = 13 Ω.  With the emitter at 2.6 V, 2.4 V are left for the LED and the C-E drop.

Answer (score 1):

Volt drop of LED: -

[image]

At 200 mA the volt drop is typically about 1.45 volts. At 300 mA it's about 1.55 volts. The data sheet tells you that 200mA is the absolute limit providing the duty cycle is 50% or less. You can activate it at extremely low duty cycles (see graph above) of tp/T = 0.001 at up to 1A but this is really pushing it and it is likely that this is not very representative of the data you want to transmit.

So, 200mA from a saturating transistor (maybe 0.2 volts dropped) leaves a volt drop across a resistor of 5 - (0.2 + 1.45 + 1.45) = 1.9 volts. A resistor value of 9.5 ohms is more appropriate.

However, you probably won't have the current capability in an IO pin to drive the base current to get that collector current. At saturation, the Hfe of the transistor might only be 10 and therefore you'll need to push 20 mA into the base - can your IO pin do this?

But it's worse than this because the 2N222A cannot get down to 0.2V saturation passing 200 mA - read the data sheet. At 150mA it will drop 0.3 volts at a base current of 15 mA. At 500mA it will drop typically 1V.

You have problems to solve in several areas to make this work but the first stage is understanding those problems!